# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on a non-object bug

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I don't know what's wrong with this.. ive tried using dd with it.. i only need to upload one file .. everytime I upload it always returns null

**Controller**

```
public function postDoTest(){
     dd( Input::file('file') ); // this returns NULL
}
```

then in My **view**

```
{{ Form::open( array( 'url' => 'files/do-test', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'file_uploader_forms' ) ) }}


{{ Form::file('file', array( 'id' => 'fileuploads', 'style' => 'display:none' ) ) }}

<button type="submit" id="upload_all" class="btn btn-upload">test</button>

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You should change `'id' => 'fileuploads'` to `'id' => 'file'`.